# Builder pattern in Ada

Tags: ada

I am still new to Ada and not very proficient in the way object orientation is handled in Ada. :(

I would like to know if it is possible to implement a *builder* like pattern in Ada? This pattern is quite common in the Java programming language.

A simple example: Let's say I want to model a person object. A person has the following attributes:

- First name
- Middle name (optional)
- Last name
- Date of birth
- Place of birth (optional)

I could implement four (overloaded) `Create` functions to cover all possible combinations:

```ada
declare
    Person_1 : Person;
    Person_2 : Person;
    Person_3 : Person;
    Person_4 : Person;
begin
    Person_1 := Create(First_Name    => "John",
                       Last_Name     => "Doe",
                       Date_Of_Birth => "1990-02-27");

    Person_2 := Create(First_Name    => "John",
                       Middle_Name   => "Michael",
                       Last_Name     => "Doe",
                       Date_Of_Birth => "1990-02-27");

    Person_3 := Create(First_Name     => "John",
                       Last_Name      => "Doe",
                       Date_Of_Birth  => "1990-02-27",
                       Place_Of_Birth => "New York");

    Person_4 := Create(First_Name     => "John",
                       Middle_Name    => "Michael",
                       Last_Name      => "Doe",
                       Date_Of_Birth  => "1990-02-27",
                       Place_Of_Birth => "New York");
end;
```

*Builder* pattern like (don't know if this is possible in Ada):

```ada
declare
    Person_1 : Person;
    Person_2 : Person;
    Person_3 : Person;
    Person_4 : Person;
begin
    Person_1 := Person.Builder.First_Name("John")
                              .Last_Name("Doe")
                              .Date_Of_Birth("1990-02-27")
                              .Build();

    Person_2 := Person.Builder.First_Name("John")
                              .Middle_Name("Michael")
                              .Last_Name("Doe")
                              .Date_Of_Birth("1990-02-27")
                              .Build();

    Person_3 := Person.Builder.First_Name("John")
                              .Last_Name("Doe")
                              .Date_Of_Birth("1990-02-27")
                              .Place_Of_Birth("New York")
                              .Build();

    Person_4 := Person.Builder.First_Name("John")
                              .Middle_Name("Michael")
                              .Last_Name("Doe")
                              .Date_Of_Birth("1990-02-27")
                              .Place_Of_Birth("New York")
                              .Build();
end;
```

First question: How could this example be implemented in Ada?

The `Build` function could check (at runtime) if all required attributes where initialized by the belonging functions.

Second question: Could this check be delegated (in a magic way) to the compiler so the following example would not compile?

```ada
declare
    Person : Person;
begin
    -- Last_Name function not called
    Person := Person.Builder.First_Name("John")
                            .Date_Of_Birth("1990-02-27")
                            .Build();
end;
```

Comment: Does java allow to perform such a check at compile time?

Comment: @VTT: To the extent that Java generics can check compile-time type safety, yes; but the approach may scale poorly for deeply nested, evolving APIs, for [example](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-March/006725.html).

Comment: This doesn’t appear to be the GoF Builder pattern, which I find quite hard to imagine a need for (in any case, but especially in this very simple example)

Comment: Most of these design patterns exist simply to work around deficiencies in the languages the GoF used. For example, the singleton pattern is a workaround for the lack of modules. In Ada, a singleton is simply a package. This pattern appears to be a workaround for the lack of default parameters, as Wright shows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One Ada way of supporting the problem as stated would be to use default values for the parameters whose values aren’t required:

```
function Create (First_Name     : String;
                 Middle_Name    : String := "";
                 Last_Name      : String;
                 Date_Of_Birth  : String;
                 Place_Of_Birth : String := "")
                return Person;
```

which accepts all your examples.

Comment: Fully agree but as I understood it, the question was more about how to enforce compilation time checks to the builder pattern.

Comment: I've gave an answer showing the builder pattern working. However, this is absolutely the better approach and is really what should be done.

Answer (score 3):

So yes, this is possible.

I ***strongly*** recommend you do not go with this approach. It have very bad performance problems, not to mention is harder to maintain. That being said, it is in fact possible (and should be in any language with dispatching). It's accomplished by an extension to a fluent pattern, which uses an intermediary type, to keep the primary type readonly. Because Ada does not have readonly fields, you will also need to use a property pattern to expose the fields in a readonly way.

Here's the spec

```ada
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

package Persons is

    type Person is tagged private;

    function First_Name(Self : in Person) return String;

    function Middle_Name(Self : in Person) return String;

    function Last_Name(Self : in Person) return String;

    function Date_of_Birth(Self : in Person) return String;

    function Place_of_Birth(Self : in Person) return String;

    type Person_Builder is tagged private;

    function Builder return Person_Builder;

    function First_Name(Self : in Person_Builder; Value : in String) return Person_Builder;

    function Middle_Name(Self : in Person_Builder; Value : in String) return Person_Builder;

    function Last_Name(Self : in Person_Builder; Value : in String) return Person_Builder;

    function Date_of_Birth(Self : in Person_Builder; Value : in String) return Person_Builder;

    function Place_of_Birth(Self : in Person_Builder; Value : in String) return Person_Builder;

    function Build(Source : in Person_Builder'Class) return Person;

private
    type Person is tagged record
        First_Name : Unbounded_String;
        Middle_Name : Unbounded_String;
        Last_Name : Unbounded_String;
        Date_of_Birth: Unbounded_String;
        Place_of_Birth: Unbounded_String;
    end record;

    type Person_Builder is tagged record
        First_Name : Unbounded_String;
        Middle_Name : Unbounded_String;
        Last_Name : Unbounded_String;
        Date_of_Birth: Unbounded_String;
        Place_of_Birth: Unbounded_String;
    end record;

end Persons;
```

and the body

```ada
package body Persons is

    function First_Name(Self : in Person) return String is (To_String(Self.First_Name));

    function Middle_Name(Self : in Person) return String is (To_String(Self.Middle_Name));

    function Last_Name(Self : in Person) return String is (To_String(Self.Last_Name));

    function Date_of_Birth(Self : in Person) return String is (To_String(Self.Date_of_Birth));

    function Place_of_Birth(Self : in Person) return String is (To_String(Self.Place_of_Birth));

    function Builder return Person_Builder is
    begin
        return Person_Builder'(To_Unbounded_String(""), To_Unbounded_String(""), To_Unbounded_String(""), To_Unbounded_String(""), To_Unbounded_String(""));
    end Builder;

    function First_Name(Self : in Person_Builder; Value : in String) return Person_Builder is
    begin
        return Person_Builder'(To_Unbounded_String(Value), Self.Middle_Name, Self.Last_Name, Self.Date_of_Birth, Self.Place_of_Birth);
    end First_Name;

    function Middle_Name(Self : in Person_Builder; Value : in String) return Person_Builder is
    begin
        return Person_Builder'(Self.First_Name, To_Unbounded_String(Value), Self.Last_Name, Self.Date_of_Birth, Self.Place_of_Birth);
    end Middle_Name;

    function Last_Name(Self : in Person_Builder; Value : in String) return Person_Builder is
    begin
        return Person_Builder'(Self.First_Name, Self.Middle_Name, To_Unbounded_String(Value), Self.Date_of_Birth, Self.Place_of_Birth);
    end Last_Name;

    function Date_of_Birth(Self : in Person_Builder; Value : in String) return Person_Builder is
    begin  
        return Person_Builder'(Self.First_Name, Self.Middle_Name, Self.Last_Name, To_Unbounded_String(Value), Self.Place_of_Birth);
    end Date_of_Birth;

    function Place_of_Birth(Self : in Person_Builder; Value : in String) return Person_Builder is
    begin
        return Person_Builder'(Self.First_Name, Self.Middle_Name, Self.Last_Name, Self.Date_of_Birth, To_Unbounded_String(Value));
    end Place_of_Birth;

    function Build(Source : in Person_Builder'Class) return Person is
    begin
        return Person'(Source.First_Name, Source.Middle_Name, Source.Last_Name, Source.Date_of_Birth, Source.Place_of_Birth);
    end Build;

end Persons;
```

Then an example program using that package

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO, Persons;
use Ada.Text_IO, Persons;

procedure Proof is
    P : Person;
begin
    P := Builder
        .First_Name("Bob")
        .Last_Name("Saget")
        .Place_of_Birth("Philadelphia, Pennsylvania")
        .Build;

    Put_Line("Hello, my name is " & P.First_Name & " " & P.Last_Name & " and I am from " & P.Place_of_Birth);
    Put_Line("Middle Name: " & P.Middle_Name);
    Put_Line("Date of Birth: " & P.Date_of_Birth);
end Proof;
```

And here's the command line output

[image]

Now let me explain. Your primary type is of course `Person`, with `Person_Builder` acting as the mutable form of it. `Builder` converts from `Person` to `Person_Builder` and `Build` converts from `Person_Builder` back to `Person`. `Person` only supports readonly access to the fields through a property pattern. Similarly, `Person_Builder` supports mutation but not through a property pattern, rather through a fluent pattern which returns the new instance each call. These modifications can then be chained as a result of fluent application.

Comment: Furthermore, you could add the builder pattern into the declarations. I'm not sure why I didn't. But it does in fact work as the one shot `P : Person := Builder.....Build;`

Comment: I had completely missed your second question, but I beleive at this point I can just get you started in the right direction and you can solve this one on your own. Inside of `Build` is where you do all your validation, and throw an exception if  invalid. You can do this through contracts if you require compile time checks (and I would strongly recommend that).

Comment: Thank you for your input. ;) I have worked on a similar solution in the last hours. ;) I created a package `Person` and a nested package `Person.Builder`. My equivalent type to your type `Person_Builder` is also a record but with one component `Temporary_Person` which has the type `Person`. The builder related functions are storing the parameter values to this component. The function `Build` returns the value of this component. I am planning to post my solution tomorrow after I have implemented a solution to mark attributes as required and optional.

Comment: From what I understood in the first place, the initial goal was to provide a way to make the compiler throw an error if the fields weren't initialized. Am I wrong because this implementation of the builder doesn't ensure this property.

Comment: @FrédéricPraca see my second comment.

Comment: Agree with your assertion on not using this method over the better.  However, I did want to suggest changing the public Person_Builder type definition to type Person_Builder(<>) is tagged limited private as that further restricts its use to your intent.  The (<>) prevents just creating a Person_Builder without calling the constructor and the limited keeps it from being copied around externally (also can optimize the internal copies in some cases).  They aren't necessary, just things to consider

Comment: Thanks @Jere. I was just quickly getting a solution written up but these are actually some rather major improvements.

Comment: @PatrickKelly No problem at all.  I did spend some time working at two other variants of your solution.  One that used heap allocation internally so that a access variable was passed at each stage instead of copying the whole record every time and one that used an aliased variable and access variables to it (again to only pass an access variable instead of full copying).  Both were on average faster, but the setup was complex enough and difficult to do safely, so I decided against suggesting them.  All were still slower than the correct solution as you pointed out.

Comment: For reference, the other two variants required the use of the Rosen Technique and the heap one needed a Limited_Controlled component to ensure the heap allocated copy got destroyed.  The heap allocated version also really just felt wrong to do.  Either way it was a fun exercise to try in the name of (computer) science.

Comment: @Jere yeah, I just wanted to get him started on the right path, with understanding how this works. I both didn't want to spend that much time solving someone elses problem, didn't want to completely do the work for him, and didn't want to encourage using a design smell. That being said, it was certainly a neat intellectual puzzle and was a fun challenge.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Java has the Builder pattern because it does not support parameters with defaults. The Builder pattern in Java creates a workaround for those who do not want to use function overloading.
Ada does have default parameters, so an Ada way to address this need, (without using overloadding) is to use default parameters, as was suggested by Simon Wright.

A benefit of this approach, is that this gives you compile time checking, whereas using the Builder pattern, apparently it is a run-time check. Using the Create function as suggested by Simon, one cannot create a Person that doesn't have a first name, for example.

So in Ada, I'd say there isn't a need to implement a Builder pattern, since better mechanisms are built into the syntax. However, if one did want to implement a builder pattern, my approach would be to use Ada streaming capabilities to build a stream of attribute objects that can be passed into a Build procedure which reads the stream, and builds an object. That is essentially what the Java Build pattern is doing. This however puts the error checking back in the run-time, rather than at compile time, as it does in Java.

Comment: I think your confusing streams with fluent pattern.

Comment: I was envisioning a form of pipeline processing, where output from one piece of the pipe can be fed into the next piece of pipe, and the pipe pieces can be hooked up in any order. However, looking more into the builder pattern, if it is meant to be a form of the fluent pattern, then I agree the approach you have in your example, is a better fit, however, as you say, I would not recommend that approach either. With Ada's stronger typing, named parameters, and default parameters, you get similar readability, plus compiler can catch errors with a single create function, at least for this problem.

Answer (score -1):

From my point of view at first sight, this would require the compiler to know the content of your builder object at compilation time and so this is not possible but I may be wrong.

One solution though, which is not really a builder pattern, might be to declare intermediate types such as

```ada
type Person_with_name is tagged record
    First_name : String(1..50);
end record;

type Person_with_last_name is new Person_With_First_Name with
record
    Last_Name : String(1..50);
end record;

type Person_with_last_name is new Person_With_Birth with
record
    Date_Of_Birth : Date;
end record;
```

And then each you would have in your *Builder* object, functions returning these types

```ada
function LastName(with_first : Person_With_First_Name, last_name : String(1..50)) return Person_With_Last_Name;

function Date_Of_Birth(with_last : Person_With_Last_Name, date_Of_Birth : Date) return Person_With_Birth;
```

And so on... But that's a bit ugly :D

Please keep in mind that I didn't compile such a code :)

On the other hand, by writing pre- and post- conditions, you could be able to check this property using Spark and then prove that, when calling *Build* on your *Builder* object, this latter is correctly initialized.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it is fine to define all attributes in a single record type. Unused attributes would then keep their default value. Especially if more attributes are optional many types would be necessary to cover all combinations. I think every time a `Builder` is used a new object must be created temporarily. This object is returned when the `Build` function is called. The `First_Name`, `Last_Name`, etc. function should return a `Builder` type. But I don't know if this is possible. The record type should be private but have to be accessible in the `Builder` related functions.